# Documentation edit submission improvement

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

Whenever I go to the edit mode in the series of documentation examples once in editor mode the main page goes back to the first entry. I have to manually go back to the example I was working on.

Let's try to edit the last entry in [Compatibility between Python 3 and Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/compatibility-between-python-3-and-python-2#t=201609020702327214381). `Return value when writing to a file object`

[image]

And see how once in edit mode the main page moves to the first example. Try it yourself.

[image]

Also it rolls back once edit is submitted for approval.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I have included images, please see it that makes it clear.